# Switching between screens defined in separate .kv (Kivy) files

Tags: python, kivy, screen

I once managed to get a multi-screen program working by having everything (including screens) defined in a single .kv file.

By using `root.current` (in .kv file) or `self.root.current` (in Python file) I was able to switch between screens. However, the .kv file grows very large and hard to maintain once there are several screens with many widgets.

This time I tried to define Screens in separate .kv files, but I can't get switching between screens to work. Every attempt so far resulted in an error (invalid syntax, screen name not defined...).

**Is there a way (or ways) to switch between screens, defined in separate .kv files?**
Here are the files I am using:

**main.py**

```
from kivy.app import App


class MainApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

**main.kv:**

```
#:include screen_1.kv
#:include screen_2.kv

#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition

ScreenManager:
    transition: NoTransition()


    Screen:
        name: "main_screen"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

            Label:
                text: "main screen"
            Button:
                text: "to screen 1"
                on_press: app.root.current = "screen_1"
            Button:
                text: "to screen 2"
                on_press: app.root.current = "screen_2"
```

**screen_1.kv:**

```
Screen:
    name: 'screen_1'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Label:
            text: "Screen 1"
        Button:
            text: "to main screen"
            on_press: app.root.current = "main_screen"
        Button:
            text: "to screen 2"
            on_press: app.root.current = "screen_2"
```

**screen_2.kv:**

```
Screen:
    name: 'screen_2'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Label:
            text: "Screen 2"
        Button:
            text: "to main screen"
            on_press: app.root.current = "main_screen"
        Button:
            text: "to screen 1"
            on_press: app.root.current = "screen_1"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Solution

1. Add [dynamic class](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes) into `screen_1.kv` and `screen_2.kv`, e.g. `<Screen1@Screen>:` and `<Screen2@Screen>:` respectively.
2. Instantiate screens, `Screen1:` and `Screen2:` in `main.kv`

## Example

### screen_1.kv

```
<Screen1@Screen>:
    name: 'screen_1'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Label:
            text: "Screen 1"
        Button:
            text: "to main screen"
            on_press: app.root.current = "main_screen"
        Button:
            text: "to screen 2"
            on_press: app.root.current = "screen_2"
```

### screen_2.kv

```
<Screen2@Screen>:
    name: 'screen_2'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"

        Label:
            text: "Screen 2"
        Button:
            text: "to main screen"
            on_press: app.root.current = "main_screen"
        Button:
            text: "to screen 1"
            on_press: app.root.current = "screen_1"
```

### main.kv

```
#:include screen_1.kv
#:include screen_2.kv

#:import NoTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.NoTransition


ScreenManager:
    transition: NoTransition()


    Screen:
        name: "main_screen"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"

            Label:
                text: "main screen"
            Button:
                text: "to screen 1"
                on_press: app.root.current = "screen_1"
            Button:
                text: "to screen 2"
                on_press: app.root.current = "screen_2"

    Screen1:

    Screen2:
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Main Screen]
[image: Img02 - Screen1]
[image: Img03 - Screen2]

Comment: Thank you, this solution works. For future reference, could you please hint me the resource/docs, where this techniquie is explained. So I will understand how it works and be able to find solution to similar problems on my own next time. Thanks.

Comment: You are most welcome. Updated post with link for [Kivy Dynamic Classes](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#dynamic-classes). Noted.

Comment: I believe I have done so, or it does not appear that way for some reason?